# Convert integer value to fractional value (decimal)

Tags: vb.net, math

Looking for a way to convert a positive number (integer) from e.g. 123 to 0.123 without using strings. Can be any size integer. Not concerned about negative values.

```
Dim value As Integer = 123
Dim num As Decimal = "." & value.ToString
```

It seems simple but I'm not sure how to do it using math. How can I convert without using strings?

Comment: Not even sure how to google this question. I tried.

Comment: Can you expand on the transformation?  Is this always to put the integer (no matter the length) immediately to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: @Craig yes that is exactly right.

Comment: Divide it by 10 ^ ceiling(log10(value)) or something.

Comment: @Arvo Perfect, thanks. That's an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the number of digits using `Log10`.  I think the best way is thusly:

```
Dim value = 123 'Or whatever other value
Dim digitCount = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value))) + 1
Dim result = value * CDec(10 ^ (-digitCount))
```

You need to use `Floor` rather than `Ceiling` in order to get the right result for 0, 10, 100, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method:

```
Dim value As Integer = 123
Dim num As Decimal = value

While Math.Abs(num) >= 1
    num = num / 10
End While
```

The Math.Abs takes care of negatives, so you could remove it as you say you're not concerned with them.

This also works:

```
Dim value as Integer = 123
Dim num as Decimal = value

num /= 10 ^ Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(value))
```

It's a little harder to see what's going on initially, but it basically finds the next power of 10 that is above the number, and divides by the 10^(that power)

*Edit* As per Craigs answer Math.Floor then add one works better than Math.Ceiling thus:

```
Dim value as Integer = 123
Dim num as Decimal = value

num /= 10 ^ (Math.Floor(Math.Log10(value)) + 1)
```

*Edit*
I just did a quick performance comparison, and on my PC doing the While loop took 851ms, and the Log10 method took 158ms. That's for 1,000,000 iterations of each.